# Woocommerce search within categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site (built on Wordpress), and have used a plugin called "Woocommerce Advanced Search".

I need to find a way to get the search to return all items that either meet the search criteria by name or description, but also if the item is in a category which matches the search term.

So if someone searches for "cameras", then I want the search to return any items that happen to have the word "cameras" in the title or description and any items in the "cameras" category.